# ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2 - MacOS Mojave 10.14.16 python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pip, psycopg2, macos-mojave

I got this issue when I try to install `psycopg2`

```
$ pip install psycopg2 ...
.
.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
```

This happens also if a try

```
$ pip install psycopg2
```

I am using virtualenv in MacOS Mojave 10.14.16 I don't remember having this issue before updating my OS.

Comment: Show the full text of the error, please. Also try `pip install psycopg2-binary`. [psycopg2-binary](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/) provides precompiled binaries for a lot of platforms and Python versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar issue and I fixed it installing openssl via Homebrew and manually linking my homebrew-installed openssl to pip:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install psycopg2
```

additionally if you don't have Command Line Tools installed before running the previous command, please run

```
xcode-select --install
```

I hope this can help you it worked for me in 10.13 High Sierra in case it does not fix the issue, please provide the complete error trace for to help you